# Easy way to set same event to some elements

Tags: javascript

Please give me idea.
How do I do in this case.

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("buttons"); //get four buttons

buttons[0].onclick = alert("hoge");
buttons[2].onclick = alert("hoge");

buttons[1].onclick = alert("fuga");
buttons[3].onclick = alert("fuga");
```

Comment: `buttons[0].onclick = buttons[2].onclick = alert.bind(window, "hoge");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
buttons[0].onclick = buttons[2].onclick = alert("hoge");
buttons[1].onclick = buttons[3].onclick = alert("fuga");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other assignment:

```
a = b = c = d = e = f = "letters!";
```

Apply to your situation:

```
buttons[0].onclick = buttons[2].onclick = function() {alert("hoge");};
```

Comment: You should probably explain why you are using `function() {...}` I'm not sure the OP knows the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("buttons"); //get four buttons

//Add buttons to own array depending on which alert to display
var buttonsHoge = [buttons[0],buttons[2]];
var buttonsFuga = [buttons[1],buttons[3]];

//Loop through each array and attach the alert to the buttons click event
jQuery.each(buttonsHoge,function(){
  $(this).click(function(){ alert("hoge"); });
});

jQuery.each(buttonsFuga,function(){
  $(this).click(function(){ alert("fuga"); });
});
```